# How can I add class(style) for output elements in countdown timer using document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've done my countdown timer simple but now I would like to add style for it in Javascript.How can I do this?Is it possible to output value different?If yes,how?

Here is source

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days  + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.countdown
{
margin:0 auto;
font-weight: 100;
font-size:3em;color: white;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-image:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown" id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle link is empty, but from the title of the question I guess, you want to add a CSS class to an element that you get using `getElementById()` in pure javascript. If so, here is an option:

```
document.getElementById('your_element_id').classList.add('class_to_add');
```

Comment: What and how exactly do you want to change?

Comment: I would like do add style for timer eache element from it should have circular bacgkround,and I don't know how to add class or id here    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days  + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";I am new in codding

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page that explains how to set an element's style by changing its class or by manipulating its style.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp